# Is it possible to allow iBeacon app work properly without GPS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, gps, ibeacon

I've been working on iOS app which interacts with iBeacon devices. Workflow is next: 
if user near iBeacon then app receiving push notification from internet.
So for recognizing if user near some iBeacon needs to be turned on next modules:

- gps
- bluetooth
- wifi/3G
- push notification

The issue is that without turned on GPS module app can't find any iBeacons. It's weird since iBeacon technology works using bluetooth only.

How to solve the following problem?
I use Xcode 6.1.1, iOS 8, CoreLocation and CoreBluetooth frameworks.

Here is a code how I implemented:

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {

    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;

    if([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {

        [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"];
    NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

    CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                                      identifier:bundleIdentifier];
    [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
    [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
}
else {

    NSLog(@"location service is disabled");
}
```

Comment: When you say "without the GPS module turned on" what do you mean?  How are you turning off the GPS?

Comment: Do you have the same problem with iOS7?. If no, the problem is caused by lack of 2 things: insert a key in Info.plist & ask for permission. I don't think that you need GPS in order to use iBeacon.

Comment: http://blog.estimote.com/post/97824495825/ios-8-pushes-location-context-to-a-new-level-lock

Comment: Paulw11, if I turn off "Location Services" in iPhone 6 by navigating Settings->Policy->Location Services  then my app doesn't receive any CLLocationManagerDelegate notifications related to finding iBeacon.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need GPS for iBeacon to work, but you do need Location Services.

This why I asked how you were "turning off the GPS", as I am not aware of any way in iOS that you can turn off the GPS receiver specifically.

When the user disables Location Services in the Settings app they aren't just turning off GPS - as the name says, they are turning off Location Services.  Location Services in iOS refers to anything that can locate the user, which includes GPS, WiFi location and iBeacon.

Comment: This is absolutely correct.  Also, make sure you have NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in your app´s Info.plist, otherwise the user won´t get prompted for location permissions.

Answer (score 0):

No, without GPS, iBeacon will not work properly. CLLocation Manager is a class in the core location framework. The delegates of CLocation Manager will not get triggered without GPS.  Here iBeacon works with the help of CLocation Manager.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region;
```

This is the delegate that is getting triggered while an iBeacon is identified in a region. This delegate will not work without GPS.